# Spring Data - findById Finds Uncommited Data Even If I Use propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW

Tags: spring, spring-data

I'm trying to learn propagations of Spring Data and I learnt that Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW always uses a brandnew transaction. When I try below code, the findById method finds the record but that record doesn't stay in database the really.

I'm expecting that the calling findById will not be able to find the record with relevant id and new transaction because save method doesn't flush the data. But in my case, it finds the record. How can it find it?

```
@Autowired
private DriverRepository driverRepository;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void saveDriver(Long driverId, Driver driver) {

    driverRepository.save(driver);

    printDriver(driverId);
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED)
public void printDriver(Long driverId) {
    Optional<Driver> existingDriverAsOptional1 = driverRepository.findById(driverId);
    Driver existingDriver1 = existingDriverAsOptional1.get();
    System.out.println(existingDriver1.getDriverName());
    System.out.println(existingDriver1.getDriverSurname());
    System.out.println(existingDriver1.getDriverTeam());
}
```

Comment: Transaction annotations are ignored if you call the method from the same class, as the call is not going through the created proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `printDriver(driverId)` does *not* create a new transaction, as the call is directly invoked on `this` and the transaction is created by an interceptor residing in a proxy around the current instance. I.e. transactions are only created for methods called from "the outside" passing the proxy and thus the interceptor.

Find more information in the reference documentation [section on declarative transactions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/data-access/transaction/declarative/tx-decl-explained.html).